# Bash loop not updating output correctly

Tags: bash, loops, echo

I wrote a test script in bash, to test my server. The test progress percentage is updated and replaced by the test status, either `OK`, or `KO`.

The following output is expected :

```
Test 1/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 2/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 3/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 4/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 5/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 6/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 7/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 8/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
```

But for some reasons, the text does not update correctly, and I get the following output :

```
Test 1/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 2/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 3/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 4/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 5/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : OK (3000/3000)
Test 6/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : Processing...
                                              0%
                                              10.00%
                                              20.00%
                                              30.00%
                                              40.00%
                                              50.00%
                                              60.00%
                                              70.00%
                                              80.00%
                                              90.00%
                                              OK (3000/3000)
Test 7/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : Processing...
                                              0%
                                              10.00%
                                              20.00%
                                              30.00%
                                              40.00%
                                              50.00%
                                              60.00%
                                              70.00%
                                              80.00%
                                              90.00%
                                              OK (3000/3000)
Test 8/8 : 10 channel(s) and 100 stream(s) : Processing...
                                              0%
                                              10.00%
                                              20.00%
                                              30.00%
                                              40.00%
                                              50.00%
                                              60.00%
                                              70.00%
                                              80.00%
                                              90.00%
                                              OK (3000/3000)
```

As you can see, once the graphical bug appears, it keeps happening. Also note that it happens at random moments, and sometimes, it does not appear at all.

Here is my printing loop :

```
for ((i=0; i < d; i++));
do
        echo "Test $((${i} + 1))/${d} : ${channelTab[i]} channel(s) and ${streamTab[i]} stream(s) : ${saveCursor}Processing..."
        sent=0
        received=0
        errors=0
        e=0
        for ((idx = 0; idx < ${channelTab[i]}; idx++));
        do
                /u/ecmg/bin/simulator ${fileNameTab[i]} > /dev/null 2<&1 &
                pourcentage=$(bc <<< "scale=2;((${idx}))/${channelTab[i]} *100")
                echo ${restoreCursor}${eraseEndOfLine}${saveCursor}${pourcentage}%
                pids[idx]=$!
                sleep .5
        done
        for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
                wait $pid
                results[e]=$(grep -a "stats" "${fileNameTab[i]}.out")
                ((e=e+1))
        done
        for ((f=0; f < e; f++));
        do
                res=$(echo "${results[f]}" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
                resArray=($res)
                ((sent=sent + ${resArray[0]}))
                ((received=received + ${resArray[1]}))
                ((errors=errors + ${resArray[2]}))
        done
        if [ "$sent" != "$received" ];
        then
                echo -e "${restoreCursor}${eraseEndOfLine}${red}KO${normal} --> ${errors} errors (${received}/${sent})"
        fi
        if [ "$sent" == "$received" ];
        then
                echo -e "${restoreCursor}${eraseEndOfLine}${green}OK${normal} (${received}/${sent})"
        fi
done
```

Here is how `${restorCursor}`, `${eraseEndOfLine}` and `${saveCursor}` are defined :

```
saveCursor=$'\033[s'
restoreCursor=$'\033[u'
eraseEndOfLine=$'\033[K'
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be due to the scroll of the terminal, when a newline is printed at the bottom of the screen, the lines are moved to the top.

a workaround may be to use `printf` or `echo -n` to avoid printing newline.